# Make a HMTL <a href> hyperlink not appear as a hyperlink

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

I'm making a website (for schoolwork) using a combination of php, html and css. I'm currently working on the initial design stages of my site and as I'm inexperienced at html / css, I am going slowly through tutorials trying to learn.

Including the hyperlink my banner looks like:[image: banner with hyperlink]

Not including the hyperlink my banner looks like:[image: banner without hyperlink]

I want to have the functionality of the link, but the visual design effect of without the link.

The necessary code is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <center>
    <div id = "indexBackgroundOne"><h2 style="font-family:verdana"> Q U E S T S &reg;</h2></div>
    </center>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using inline css you can use like this -

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <center>
    <div id = "indexBackgroundOne"><h2 style="font-family:verdana;text-decoration: none;color:black;"><a href=""  style="text-decoration: none;color:black;"> Q U E S T S &reg;</a></h2></div>
    </center>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your style.css file

```
#indexBackgroundOne h2 a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
}
```

Here is a sample code :

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <style>
    #indexBackgroundOne h2 a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color:black;
    }
    </style>
    <center>
    <div id = "indexBackgroundOne"><h2 style="font-family:verdana"> Q U E S T S &reg;</h2></div>
    </center>
</html>
```

Comment: this doesn't include the link

Comment: @Mindless , sorry now it does

Answer (score 0):

try this for the desired effect:

```css
.no-style {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div id = "indexBackgroundOne">
      <h2 style="font-family:verdana">
          <a href="" class="no-style">Q U E S T S &reg;</a>
      </h2>
  </div>
</center>
```

or if you want inline styles:

```html
<center>
    <div id = "indexBackgroundOne">
        <h2 style="font-family:verdana;">
            <a href="" style="text-decoration:none;color:black;"> Q U E S T S &reg;
            </a>
        </h2>
    </div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.noline{
text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <center>
    <div id = "indexBackgroundOne"><a class="noline"href="#your link"><h2 style="font-family:verdana"> Q U E S T S &reg;</h2></a></div>
    </center>
</html>
```

you can make a class and add it to  and make text-decoration:none in css